# Prediction errors for OLS with unevenly distributed covariate

Tags: regression, mixed-model, predictive-models, least-squares

Suppose I have a simple OLS model for a covariate that is not evenly distributed.  Is there a way to get a prediction error estimate that reflects that greater uncertainty for covariate values with few samples.

For example, in the following fit, the model is not a very good for the 3 samples with `x=1`, so I'd want much larger prediction errors for large `x` and smaller errors for small `x`.

[image: Data and OLS fit]

Comment: The standard prediction interval does *exactly* what you ask for.  There is a more serious issue in your data, though: a line is a poor fit and the values in the right half of the plot have undue leverage: they cause the line to miss almost all the points where $x$ exceeds 0.05 or so.  The cure for both these problems begins by adopting a suitable model for the response followed by a non-linear transformation of the explanatory variable, perhaps a square root, to make the relationship closer to linear.

Comment: Thanks @whuber.  A non-linear transformation definitely helps.  But what do you mean by adopting a suitable model for the response?  Like use non-gaussian errors?

Comment: And for the standard prediction interval, isn't that a fixed standard error for each coefficient?  So it will increase with the leverage, but it doesn't really react to the sparsity of samples for x>0.1 like you'd have with a Gaussian Process, right?

Comment: Take a look at the formula for the prediction interval: it increases (asymptotically linearly) as a function of the Mahalanobis distance of the explanatory variable from the point of averages of all those variables in the data.  That accounts for both the sparsity and value of the values.  The coefficient standard errors alone do not determine the prediction interval.

Comment: @whuber that's true, but it seems like the prediction interval is far too small and will decrease to zero as more points are sampled from the main cluster with x<0.2, even if no further points are sampled around x=1.0.  I get much better results by bootstrap resampling.

Comment: That's no surprise, given the model is such a poor one for these data. Regardless, no prediction interval will decrease to zero, not even asymptotically, so it looks like you're not computing a prediction interval or you're not computing it correctly. I suspect you might be computing a *confidence interval* for the *fitted values.*  That will converge to some line (even when the model is poor).